# Filter table data with Jquery based on HTML input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Can you please help me code Jquery right way so i can filter HTML table based on text input. So far this is my code:

```
    <input type="text" name="inputdata" id="inputdata" onkeyup="filter()">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr name="data">
               <?php foreach ($products as $row) { ?>
                 <td><?php echo $row->id_product; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
               <?php }  ?>
            </tr>
```

Jquery code

```
<script>
    function filter(){
        inp = $('#inputdata').val()
        $("tr").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text().indexOf(inp) == -1;
        }).hide();
    }
</script>
```

So my problems are:

1. Search is case sensitive
2. When i input some string, let's say Pants, Jquery filters data, but then i have to refresh a page, so i can search again. Or let me put this other way... When i delete inputted data in search field, table isn't refreshed. It just stay on Pants data, so for another search i have to reload web page
3. `<th>` are removed when searching for data. If i declare `$('tr[name=data]').filter(function() {` search stop working

thx in advance for helping me!

Comment: What did you try and what is wrong?

Comment: I have writed down my 3 problems under the code...

Comment: Those aren't problems, they are requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should take care of your issues:

```
<script>
function filter(){
    inp = $('#inputdata').val()
    // This should ignore first row with th inside
    $("tr:not(:has(>th))").each(function() {
        if (~$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf( inp.toLowerCase() ) ) {
            // Show the row (in case it was previously hidden)
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Dude you totaly fixed first two problems! thank you kind sir! Thank you

Comment: I've added also a fix for the 3th issue (rows with th are now ignored)

Comment: Yep, this totaly did it! Really thank you for that. Look like i got still much to learn, how to handle Jquery code.

Comment: Yw.. btw you have the same last name as my uncle :D

Comment: No way! :) Where is your uncle from? Probably you are Italian and your uncle is from Slovenia or Croatia... Did i guess right? :)

Comment: Yep .. he is from Maribor ;)

Comment: Nice! Cheers to your uncle and you for solving my problem! Tnx again

Comment: You made it looks like so simple! (I'm not a web developer, but needed to do something on a page). Great job!